# Skipping outputs from the QGIS Batch Processing?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing, json, batch

I am doing a lot of processing in batch with the r.sun model from GRASS 7.2.1 in QGIS 2.18.9.
I am using the r.sun model with intention to reuse for further raster calculations the Irradiation raster and the Diffuse irradiation raster. The model computes also the Ground reflected irradiation, the Global irradiance and the Insolation time rasters, which I don't need for my further analysis. 
So, I need just 2 of 5 output calculations for making further analysis.

I am interested in if I can skip somehow this outputs. I know I can put them easily all in one folder/TMP with autofill and then delete them after, but I would love just to skip their creation by default to spare the processing time as it is really long (30min per computation).

I can manage some simple code lines and the only idea I got is to export this batch process in JSON and set the skipping of this data creation there and relaunch it from the console. 
Any suggestions about how to do it or some better idea for someone who is not able to program it by scratch?

Comment: It would be helpful to provide more background and context on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hi @Aaron, I am using the r.sun model with the intention to reuse for further raster calculations the Irradiation raster and the Diffuse irradiation raster. The model computes also the Ground reflected irradiation, the Global irradiance and the Insolation time rasters, which I don't need for my further analysis. Than you for your interest in helping out, I will update my first question with this information also.